# P-MOS control and capactive load

Tags: mosfet, capacitor, powermosfet

I am trying to drive an high capacitive load with a P-Mosfet.

I added a PTC to limit the current, but it doesn't seen to be working.
The mosfet is often killed.

Can anybody help and provide a 'simple' solution to this issue please ?

Here is the schematics.

Thanks !!
[image]

Simulation give me ~20A pulse at startup with a 0.5ohm capacitor and minimal PTC resistor of 0.5ohm.
[image]

Comment: The PTC thermal fuse is limiting your initial current to "only" 200A and after it trips only 85A while your capacitor charges with a time constant of 0.9 ms.  An inrush current limiter *might* work, but the resulting RC time constant will be far smaller than the thermal time constant so you'd really be better off with a pulse-rated resistor to bring the current down to something manageable.  How often are you charging the capacitor and how quickly do you need it charged?

Comment: thanks for your feedback.
I don't understand how the PTC limits to only 200A. the minimal resistance is given for 0.5ohm in the datasheet. 
https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2106070106_Fuzetec-Tech-FRVL050-120F_C2687103.pdf

the capacitor is loaded only at power on.
rising/loading time is not important for my usage ;)
it's a "latch/power on/off" circuit.

Comment: That was a mistake on my part; the Rmin of the PTC is 0.5 ohms, which, combined with the RDSon of the MOSFET, mean you have 1.1 ohms in series with the capacitor at the moment the MOSFET turns on, which limits your current to 91A.  After the PTC trips, its resistance rises to 1.17 ohms which limits the current to 60A, both of which are well above the MOSFET's pulsed drain current limit of 22A and outside any part of the SOA.  I would recommend a larger MOSFET along with a wirewound 50W resistor to put the inrush current back inside the SOA.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. I don't know how I failed to read the SOA so badly.
I'll order some HUASHUO HSU0139.
https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2209221830_HUASHUO-HSU0139_C701018.pdf
pulse drain is at 100A, and continuous at 30A... if I understand correctly the spec.
but I still don't understand the SOA. for this MOSFET, SOA seems to indicate 1A in DC current with VGS a -100V

Answer (score 2):

The 9120 has a max pulsed current rating of 22A. A 500uF electrolytic capacitor has an ESR < 0.5 ohms. The FET must supply a minimum (probably higher) 200 A pulse. The PTC isn’t fast enough nor does it limit the current sufficiently. Currents this high are probably not healthy for the capacitor either.

Update:
There is another reason that the   FET may fail . The max VDS of the 9120 is 100V. Your power source has a max value of 100V. It should have some headroom of at least 20V.
End update.

The operating current at 100 \$\Omega \$ load is only 1A.

The simplest solution is an FET with a much higher pulse current. Couple with a series drain resistance to limit the current to < the max pulsed current.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot for this answer. 
I'll order some HUASHUO HSU0139. 
datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2209221830_HUASHUO-HSU0139_C701018.pdf 
pulse drain is at 100A, and continuous at 30A... if I understand correctly the spec. but I still don't understand the SOA. for this MOSFET, SOA seems to indicate 1A in DC current with VGS a -100V.
but if I understand correctly , PTC has a long reaction time, and temperature won't increase fast enought from 0.5ohm to 1.17ohm ?
https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2106070106_Fuzetec-Tech-FRVL050-120F_C2687103.pdf

Comment: PTC is the opposite of what you want here.  The PTC in your circuit is at minimum resistance right when you need maximum resistance and frankly I'm surprised it didn't blow up as well.  You need a large resistance at the start when your capacitor is discharged.  A NTC inrush current limiter could work but with such a small capacitance it wouldn't have time to change resistance before the capacitor was charged up, so a fixed resistor is a good choice here.  50W resistors can be had for a few dollars.

Comment: I won't have space for a 50W resistor. I'll have to find a smarter solution. I'll have a look at NTC IRL.

Comment: any reference to advise for an NTC that could handle such current/voltage ?

Comment: @user2796876: the FET that you choose should have a rating of VDSmax > 120V. See my.update.

Comment: The gate is not being driven properly. It is in the linear range to long causing the MOSFET to get hot and fry. Put a scope on the gate and output it will become obvious.

Comment: @Gil: Good point. Driving it with a lower impedance makes addressing the capacitive inrush more imperative.

Comment: I checked the gate rising time, commutation seems to happen in ~60us with no load.
for input voltage, in fact, the power supply is lithium battery with a max voltage from 10S (36V) to 22S (92V). I don't expect spikes going up to 100V. but OK, I can put 120V mosfet if needed.

Comment: Before you do a lot of work look at the safe area curve published by the MOSFET manufacturer, you probably are well within the curve if it is driven properly. Not all parts with the same number have the same data sheet. Great thing about MOSFETs unlike transistors they can survive a short high current spike. There major failure is voltage where transistors are current.